# If $4 \mid x^{2}+y^{2} \implies 4\mid x^{2}$and $4\mid y^{2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisibility

I have a proof by contradiction but I’m not Sure if it’s correct .

**My proof:**

$4 \mid x^{2}+y^{2} \iff x^{2}+y^{2} =4n.$ other words it’s a multiple of $4$.

*By the way of contradiction:* suppose that $4 \nmid x^2$ and $4 \nmid y^2$

$$\iff x^2 \neq 4a, y^2 \neq 4b$$
$$\iff x^{2}+y^{2} \neq 4(a+b)$$

This means that $x^{2}+y^{2}$ it’s not a multiple of $4$. Which is a contradiction.

$\implies 4\mid x^{2}$and $4\mid y^{2}$

Comment: The negation of "A and B" is "not A or not B".

Comment: Try to see what are squares mod $4$ and it is easier to prove your claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct.

If you negate conjunction then you get disjunction so $4\nmid x^2$ **or** $4\nmid y^2$.

So suppose $4\nmid x^2$ then $2\nmid x$ so $x$ is odd. But then $x^2$ is odd and so $y^2=4n-x^2$ is also odd. So $x=2a+1$ and $y=2b+1$. Now we have $$4a^2+4a+4b^2+4b+2 =4n$$ and if we divide this by two we get $$2a^2+2a+2b^2+2b+1 =2n$$
$$2(a^2+a+b^2+b) +1 =2n $$which is contradiction since on LHS we have odd and on RHS we have even number.

Comment: Can i use the same method to prove that : If $7 \mid x^{2}+y^{2} \implies 7\mid x,y$

Comment: Basicly yes, but I suggest you rather use modular arithmetic in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not correct. If it were, you could use the same method to prove

> If $4\mid x+y$ then $4\mid x$ and $4\mid y$

which is but falsified by $x=3$, $y=5$.

So try again.